# Use of JsonForms tester ranks

Tags: json, jsonforms

I’m using JsonForms for my form creation in React. I’m working on creating a test r and was wondering why it needs a rank?

```
import { rankWith, scopeEndsWith } from '@jsonforms/core';

export default rankWith(
  3, // what’s the use for this?
  scopeEndsWith('rating')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The rank is how high it should be in terms of the rendering list.

If you had one component with a tester with a rank of 1

```
export default rankWith(
  1,
  scopeEndsWith('rating')
);
```

and another tester with a rank of 2

```
export default rankWith(
  2,
  scopeEndsWith('rating')
)
```

then the component with a tester that has rank 1 will be used instead of the one with rank 2

Comment: It's actually the oppostite. The rank is a priority, the higher one wins.